# react-test-renderer cause TypeError: host.fileExists is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was getting error that `react-test-renderer` is not found, so I installed it but including it in package.json causes another error. This can be version incompatibility. but I am not sure what package and which version I should use. currently I have below in my package.json

```js
    "@types/react": "^16.8.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21",
    "react-intl": "^5.12.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "react-transition-group": "4.3.0"
```

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this issue by specifically 4.7.4, added below in my package.json:

```
 "typescript": "4.7.4",
```